# How to explain that very small time windows take longer to emit output compared to larger time windows in an Apache Flink streaming application?

Tags: apache-flink, amazon-kinesis

I made an experiment with my Apache Flink streaming application trying out different sizes to the tumbling time window. I fed the application the same data each time and measured the time the application took to emit data after doing some calculations. As expected, a large time window took a longer time to emit the output than a smaller window, but only up to a point. When the window became smaller then say, 14ms, the overhead costs (I guess) of the computation made it so that the time to emit the output took longer than when using say, a 16ms window.

How would you explain this, specifically in an Apache Flink streaming application? What are the **specifics** of these overhead costs? The application is integrated with Kinesis Data Analytics.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what is being measured, and how? As @benoitparis mentioned, it's not clear how you could get meaningfully comparable results for these small windows, given the impact of the network buffer timeout (and also the auto-watermarking interval, if you are using event time). Your choice of state backend, and whether or not your window results are being incrementally aggregated, are also likely to have a significant impact. And is the number of events in each window being kept constant, or is the throughput constant, or ... ?

Answer (score 1):

The network memory buffer's default value is 100ms. It stores your records for at most 100ms before sending them, or if the buffer is full.

To me, measuring the performance of any window size under this value will have little meaning. I guess the overhead you mention might become dominant, since your system is also waiting for the 100 ms to be elapsed (I'm assuming you're not filling the buffers, [which default to 32KiB](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/ops/config.html#taskmanager-memory-segment-size); which would be 2MiB/s if they're filled every 15ms).

Try setting [execution.buffer-timeout](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/ops/config.html#execution-buffer-timeout) to 5 (ms) for optimizing latency, or to **-1 for optimizing throughput**, and reexecute your workload.

Since this is Kinesis Data Analytics, you might have to do it [programatically](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/datastream_api.html#controlling-latency):

```
env.setBufferTimeout(5);

env.generateSequence(1,10).map(new MyMapper()).setBufferTimeout(5);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am just interested in what specific overheads can occur that makes the program emit slower when using really small windows. Maybe you answered it, then I didn't understand the answer. :)